# Brightest image pixel with neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I’m trying to train a neural network to find the brightest pixel for each image in a dataset.
I’ve started with a simple rgb images dataset with 3 random grey values:

```
def generate():
    a = random.randrange(0, 255)
    b = random.randrange(0, 255)
    c = random.randrange(0, 255)
    return a, b, c

def colors (a, b, c):
    for m in range(height):
           for n in range(30):
                   img.putpixel( (n,m), (a, a, a))        
    for m in range(height):
           for n in range(30,60):
                   img.putpixel( (n,m), (b, b, b))        
    for m in range(height):
           for n in range(60, 90):
                   img.putpixel( (n,m), (c, c, c))
    return img

for i in range (1000):   
    a, b, c = generate()
    width = 90
    height = 90
    img = Image.new('RGB', [width,height])
    img = colors(a,b,c)
    img.save('img/%d.bmp'%(i))
```

Then I create the array with the images and the label list with the highest pixel value:

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = []
y = []

files = glob.glob ('img/*bmp')

for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    biggest = np.amax(image)
    y.append (biggest)    
    X.append (image)

X = np.array(X)
X = X.astype('float32') / 255

print(X.shape)
```

I set the train/test sizes and transform the label list into an array:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split    

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
y_test = np.asarray(y_test)
```

And here comes trouble: I can’t even understand what kind of modeling problem is, because it looks different from classification problems. Here I have a different target value for each image and if I try to adapt some models I’ve already used (adjusting the values) I got very high loss and very low accuracy.
Here a model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (11, 11), activation='relu', input_shape=(90, 90, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(5,5))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (9, 9), activation='relu',))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(4,4))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(255, activation = 'softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                epochs=40,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

I also think I need to customize the loss function and the accuracy, because it’s not only a true/false problem: an output value close to the target can’t be considered as “false”. Now I’m not totally sure if the biggest problem is the training model or the loss function.

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. You don't need to use Neural Nets to solve problems that might be solved much faster using very basic algorithms. Right now, your CNN consists of different convolutional and pooling layers that change your input image in a way that the pixel you are looking for might be lost during transformations and calculations.

Comment: I'm sure it could be solved faster without NN, but it's an exercise and I have to use them. I'll start changing the layers and see what happens.

Comment: Your problem is not a classification problem, but a regression one.

Comment: I've tried with regression models, but it always return the same error: "Incompatible shapes: [50,90,90,1] vs. [50,1]" and it doesn't fix changing layers parameters, it always seems to expect an output with at the same dimensions of the input, not one-dimensional.

Comment: I've found a solution: instead using a target array with only the brightest pixel value for each image, I create 1x1 images with that value, I put them in a numpy array and use it as target.